# How to scan an android device over another android device over BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can somebody tell me whether an android phone can act as a Ble simulator.I am developing an application to retrieve data over BLE from a heart rate monitor.I currently do not have the heart rate monitor and so i want to use an android Phone(Nexus 5) as a Bluetooth LE device and scan this Nexus 5 from the other android Phone which has BLE functionality(Another Nexus 5).I do not want the other android Phone to act as Peripheral; i simply want to check whether the code i have written for scanning the BLE works or not but i do not have the real heart monitor to do that as of now so just wanted to use another Nexus 5 to check whether the scan works or not.Please help.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In short : You can't.

Comment: Currently Android SDK does not allow sending out advertisement, so there is no way you can scan an Android device using BLE

Comment: HTC and Samsung pre-4.3 had Broadcom stack which might do it. Motorola Razr on some android 2.34 or something also had a stack which might work in the Peripheral role.

It's just Google being a bit slow with verifying and enabling it I guess. Right now we need Google to fix Android 4.4 authentication on Nexus reference phones. Seems Samsung have fixed their version of 4.4

Comment: @henrik I didn't deeply dig into HTC stack or Motorola stack, but I am sure that Samsung one cannot work in Peripheral role. This is written in "Samsung BLE SDK Guide and Hints": http://developer.samsung.com/ble